# Load two programs on AVR chip

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, avr, bootloader

I'm trying to load two programs onto an AVR chip, but I can't find any resources on how to do this.

The purpose of this is to have the chip start running the first program and the first program jumps (using assembly) to the second (which is loaded at a second point in memory). I know this sounds useless, but there is a larger point to it which I want to implement later on.

Is there a way to load programs at a specified point in memory and accomplish this task? Or perhaps is there a way to generate one hex file that could do this otherwise?

Thanks in advance, and I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What specific AVR are you using?  There are lots of bootloader examples for the ATmega32U4 and you might check out the AVR109 application note.

Comment: You should be able to modify the linker file to handle this.

Comment: It does not sound useless - that's exactly what a bootloader does for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start address of your code is normally determined by the linker script or settings.  The default for your toolchain will be to run from reset (i.e. the reset vector will point to the start address of the code).  Your secondary program needs to be located in a different memory space (via the linker settings) and your primary program will simply need to jump to to the second.

Some gotchas you may need to be wary of; your primary program may not leave I/O and peripherals in the "reset" state, so you secondary program should not make any assumptions.  Before making the jump, it is probably important that you disable any peripherals that may be generating interrupts.

As far as combining the hex files, that can be achieved easily with a text editor if you are careful and prepared to interpret the hex records manually or more flexibly (and less error prone) with the [SRecord tool](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/).

One problem you may encounter is that while the code itself may be separately located, the vector table in AVR is fixed and will be shared between the two programs.  The interrupt vector tables for the two programs must be identical and must share handlers - that is not straightforward if the handlers need to communicate with whichever program is "running".  The simplest solution is to arrange it so that only one of the programs uses interrupts.  SRecord will usefully resolve or warn of conflicts where both hex files define overlapping memory regions, and I think you can arrange it so that one file overrides the other.

Comment: this is very helpful and pretty much what I'm looking for, do you by any chance know of a good Mac alternative to SRecord, or if SRecord can be compiled on Mac?

Comment: @user2009114 According to the SRecord project web-site *"SRecord runs on almost any flavor of UNIX."* - that would almost certainly include OSX. I have only ever used the pre-built Windows binaries.  The project README file says build instructions are in the "BUILDING" folder on the download tar ball.  It is a simple application, I imagine wit is a simple build.

Comment: @user2009114 : .. that said a quick Google yields [this OSX issue](http://sourceforge.net/p/srecord/support-requests/8/), but a solution is offered [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/srecord/discussion/248569/thread/dd92d2e6/f5eb/) - though that indicates another possible problem too.

Comment: great, thanks so much! I just have one more quick question about the linker. so basically, when I run avr-gcc -o ..., I would add to the second program an extra argument -Wl,-section-start=.text=0x8000 and then in the first program I would jump to the address x8000 to start running? sorry, I'm really new to embedded systems

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a bootloader.  I've implemented this in Microchip's PICs, not AVR, but the trick is in the linker files.

The bootloader runs on a power up.  It looks for new application firmware to burn into the flash.  If there is no new firmware, it look to see if there is new application firmware.  If there is, then it jumps to the application's reset vector.  The application starts to run as if it was just a power up.

The trick is that the linker file for the bootloader and application are coupled together.  The bootloader reserves address 0x0000 to 0x0FFF.  The application reserves addresses 0x1000 to 0xFFFF.  Also the bootloader and application need to agree on where the application starts.  It may not be address 0x1000.

Comment: Additionally, the hex files will either need to be merged, or else the programmer software will need to be run with config options so that it does not erase the entire chip when programming the second file.

Comment: I'm using an arduino with an Atmega128, so there's a bootloader already on there (optiboot, I believe). The issue here I think is that I am trying to load two programs on top of the bootloader. So essentially, the bootloader launches program one which is sort of a kernel that jumps to program two that sits somewhere else in memory. Sorry, If I misunderstood your answer. I'm trying to use avrdude as the programmer software, so maybe there's a way I can use that to load up the two programs at separate prespecified slots in memory?

Answer (score 0):

I too use this technique for bootloader plus application on a PIC processor.  As the previous poster mentioned, the first part of the problem is to locate the two programs with the linker so they do not overlap. After building the tow programs separately I use Hexmate to combine the hex files of both programs into a single hex file.  You can get a copy of this utility for windows PCs at http://www.schmalzhaus.com/Tools/HexmateInstructions.html